# Nav Drawer with View Pager causing Overlapping Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a Nav drawer and view pager in an activity. 
The problem is the screens  overlap. When I click on a different item in the nav drawer, it changes to the appropriate screen but the view pager stays the same. In the view pager getItem(), i would call a fragment with Fragment.newInstance(int index). I tried changing the getItem() method in the view pager to use the same code as the nav drawer and replace the current fragment, however that gives me " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment". I tried getting rid of the ID of the items by removing the fragment and committing the change. It didn't fix the error. 
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private String[] titles;
private ListView drawerList;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private int currentPosition = 0;
private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;`

MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;
ViewPager pager;


private class DrawerItemClickListener implements      ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,    long id) {
        //code to run when the item gets clicked
        selectItem(position);
    }
 }

;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);
    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    //find view pager
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    //set view pager adapter
    pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

    //item user clicks on is highlighted
    //with simple_list_item_activated_1
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, titles));
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    //if mainactivity is newly created,
    //use selectItem() to display HomeFragment
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        setActionBarTitle(currentPosition);
    } else {
        selectItem(0);
    }

    //create the actionbarToggle
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
        //called when a drawer has settleed in a completely closed state

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
                    if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                        currentPosition = 0;
                    }
                    if (fragment instanceof EducationFragment) {
                        currentPosition = 1;
                    }
                    if (fragment instanceof TechnicalSkillsFragment) {
                        currentPosition = 2;
                    }
                    if (fragment instanceof WorkExpFragment) {
                        currentPosition = 3;
                    }
                    setActionBarTitle(currentPosition);
                    drawerList.setItemChecked(currentPosition, true);
                }
            }
    );
}




private Fragment selectItem(int position) {
    //currentPosition for savedInstanceState
    currentPosition = position;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(fragment !=null){
        ft.remove(fragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new EducationFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new TechnicalSkillsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new WorkExpFragment();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
    }


    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();


    //set title and close the drawer
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)) {
        setActionBarTitle(position);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }
    return fragment;
}
  public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return selectItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
```

Comment: A `FragmentTransaction` only handles `Fragment`s and their `View`s. Your `ViewPager` is apparently defined in `MainActivity`'s layout, so it will not be replaced by the transaction. One option is to put the `ViewPager` in its own `Fragment` which you load at startup, and will be replaced when you perform your transaction.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I didn't think about that. I'll try it.